# How to know if the First Boot Device is the HDD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am working in a security check project(is an application that check the policy security of my university), and I need know things like if the first boot device is the HDD and if the BIOS is protected by password. All this from windows and linux(Ubuntu) terminal. I found a utility on linux "dmidecode", but the information that it command provide me I think that is no util for me research or I dont know how interpret it. Can somebody help me?